# ZF3 Database Adapter Configuration

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework3

I am working on ZF3 framework for a web Application. I want to configure multiple MYSQL databases in ZF3 which should work in below manner:

I will specify multiple MYSQL servers in the global.php file of ZF3 as below.

```
return [
'db' => [
        'driver'   => 'Pdo_Mysql',
        'dbname'   => 'testDB',
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => '******',
                'servers'    => [
                        'host' => 'db.server-1',
                        'host' => 'db.server-2',
                        ...
                ]
    ],
];
```

While connecting to database, ZF3 should connect to 'db.server-1' always, if 'db.server-1' is not reachable then ZF3 should connect to 'db.server-2' without throwing DB error.

Kindly help me with the configuration if possible.

Comment: What have you tried to solve your issue? Can you add that? You should also add any errors and possibly relevant research. On the other hand, why would you need to specify this? Judging by how you're trying to set this up, you need a load balancer for your database servers (so you end up with a single host/IP), as the issue with reachability is database-server-side, not application (ZF3) side. I would suggest you start looking in that direction, this is not something you should solve in your application.

Comment: Also, as another side note, re-using an associative key in the same array would cause the previous value to be overwritten by the latter. `db.server-1` no longer exists in this array.